# IntelliJ: Ant reports one error. No indication of where or what failed

Tags: intellij-idea, ant

I'd love to post the log but it's company property.  It reports:  `Ant build completed with one error and --- warnings in 39s at 8/28/2018 5:35 PM`

I find this behavior rather un-intuitive in that I am not clear on where I am supposed to look to find the error.  there is no 'build failed' or 'error:' message in the log.  Nonetheless IntelliJ believes it is an error, as it interrupts the launch configuration process.

What is the assumed convention of Ant here that I am supposed to know where to look for the error?

Comment: Does command line Ant report it properly? Any tools exit with non-zero code?

Comment: I will assume that it is being reported as an error since it does interrupt the sequence of ant target executions in IntelliJ whereas previously this process worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be an ant tag which output the message:
`Result: 1`

This was regarded as an error.  Slightly disappointing that I had to track this down in an output script containing several hundred lines.